# Create Class Function for PDO Insertion

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to construct a class and function to insert data into an SQL database using PDO. I can successfully connect and I can insert the data using a regular insert. However I'm finding it difficult to construct separate class equivalent.

This is how the

```
//get variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Create array
$data = array(
   "username"=>"'$username'",
    "email" => "'$email'",
);

// Insert array
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO tableName(username,email) VALUES(:username,:email)",$data);

// Check if it was inserted
   if($insert > 0 ) {
      return 'The data was inserted!';
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
require_once("createUser.class.php");

$createUser  = new user();
```

and then in `createUser.class.php` have a function that inserts the data. I'm not really sure how to do it though. I've tried a few options from Google and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Sidenote: You left out a `$` for `username = $_POST['username'];` and a possible missing quote in `"username"=>"'$username",` or quote too many.

Comment: Thanks, I updated them.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php

Class user extends database {

 public function __construct($name, $email)
 {
   //this->conn is in the extended class database
   $query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName(username,email) VALUES(?, ?)")
   try {
      $query->execute(array($name, $email));
      return 'The data was inserted';
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return "Something went wrong";
   }
 }

}

?>
```

And than to create a user:

```
require_once("createUser.class.php");

$createUser  = new user('Daan','info@info.nl');
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean "Class user extends database" makes no sense

Comment: @YourCommonSense What would be a good answer? I need to explain it or write the class? Or even both?

Comment: Good answer would be too long to write. A couple years in college probably will do

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree. So you are saying that nobody can answer this question without a downvote from you?